# How to zoom mark_geoshape to a specific region in Altair?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I'm currently working with a geodataframe for New York City. However, I want my chart to only show a specific part of the city. Is there a way to set the latitude and longitude max and min in a mark_geoshape?

I would like my chart to show only from latitude 40.64 tot 40.84, and longitude -74.01 to -73.9.

Here's my current code:

```
ntaMap = alt.Chart(ntaData).mark_geoshape(
    fill='whitesmoke',
    stroke='gray',
    strokeWidth=0.5
).encode(
    tooltip=['NTAName','BoroName']
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=500,
    title='Neighborhood Tabulation Areas'
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)

ntaMap
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do see arguments for `latitude` and `longitude` under `encode` - https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html#altair.Chart.encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `scale` to zoom and `translate` to pan ([Example notebook](https://github.com/uwdata/visualization-curriculum/blob/master/altair_cartographic.ipynb))

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


world = data.world_110m.url

alt.Chart(alt.topo_feature(world, 'countries')).mark_geoshape(
    fill='#2a1d0c', stroke='#706545', strokeWidth=0.5
).project(
    type='mercator', scale=400, translate=[100, 550])
```

[image]